# Git - how to proceed with unpushed commits to development branch?

Tags: git, git-bash

We have development branch.

From time to time I merge development to my branch with:

```
git checkout development
git pull
git checkout my_branch
git merge development
```

Now however, by mistake while I was on development I wrote `git merge my-branch`.

And the commits from my other branch are now appearing as "5 outgoing" commits on my local development.

We are prohibited to push directly to development. We should use only pull-requests.

Now when I switch to development to make another branch for example - I see unpushed commits.

How should I proceed in this case? My feature branch has been merged with development. But these local commits still remain.

If I delete my local repo and clone again will this help to solve the situation in the least painful way?

Comment: Make sure you have no unstaged changes and run `git reset --hard origin/development` while on the `development` branch. This will point your local development branch to be the same as the upstream version.

Comment: I would just delete `development` and never check it out again! Use `origin/development` from now on. ;)

Comment: (cont... or after deleting it, check it out again next time you want it locally, if you still do for some reason.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My feature branch has been merged with development. But these local commits still remain.

Only locally. You've updated `development`, but not `origin/development`, right? And you can't have pushed anyway, if it's prohibited.

> If I delete my local repo and clone again will this help to solve the situation in the least painful way?

That will solve your issue in the *most* painful way. You'll lose your local changes for no reason!

You can simply reset the local branch with

```
git checkout development
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/development
```

Before running `reset --hard`, *always* double-check you know the current state. If `git status` shows *any* local changes, save or stash them first.

In fact, before doing anything in git make sure you know the current state. If you don't want to use a fancy shell prompt, get used to running `git status` *a lot* to avoid this and many other trivial mistakes.

Comment: This is the way to go (I've upvoted). I would definitely consider asking "why do you have a local `develop` branch in the first place?". Not that you are the only one that uses it.... I normally see flows using it but you might just as well do your updates like this: `git fetch origin; git merge origin/develop`. And that's it. No moving around.

Comment: @eftshift0, I have a local development branch because when I create a new branch I use this: 1. git checkout development  2. git pull 3. git checkout -b new-branch-name 4. git push -u origin new-branch-name . Do you have a better suggestion to create a branch without having local development?

Comment: Sure! `git fetch origin; git checkout -b new-branch-name origin/develop; git push -u origin @`... as I said: no jumping around.

Comment: I'd recommend adding `--no-track` to the end of @eftshift0's command. When you create a new branch from `origin/*` it tracks it by default.